# modules and language in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

let assume that the structure of the files as the following

- App

  - Config
    ..... until
  - Modules

    - Admin (inside Admin folder will be controllers and views model config and language)

      - Language

        - en

          - home.php
        - ar

          - home.php

So, my problem is when I want to use lang function I will put the name of the file and then the key of the thing you want to retrieve. Therefore let's say I called the function like that
lang('home.title') home represents the file name and the title represents the key. But it does not retrieve anything from the file and it returns home.title so do I need to put all my translation files
in one folder which is the one inside the app folder? or there is a solution?

Comment: would be nice if you could tell us if my answer helped

Comment: Oh I just noticed that someone did reply to my question. Im grateful to you to reply to my question. I already skipped this problem I tried to find any solutions but did not find anything. So I just skipped it. Im not sure if your answer is the solution but Im really thankful for answering the question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am currently testing this framework and want to build a modular HMVC-like app, too. I structured it like you and stumbled upon the same question. I took a look into the core code and found the problem (explanation at the end).

Assuming the namespace to e.g. a controller in the admin module will look like "\App\Modules\Admin\Controllers" and the $psr4 variable in your Autoload config class looks like

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH,
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'App'      => APPPATH, // This might be missing
];
```

you will just have to include the namespace and path to the module:

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH,
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'App'      => APPPATH, // This might be missing
    'App\Modules\Admin'      => APPPATH . 'Modules' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Admin',
];
```

If you do not want to add all paths manually you could define the constructor of your Autoload class as follows:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $dir = new DirectoryIterator(APPPATH . 'Modules');
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $this->psr4['App\Modules\\' . $fileinfo->getFilename()] = $fileinfo->getRealPath();
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Problematic is that during the parsing process the path to language files is somewhat hardcoded and will later on be appended to one of the paths known to the autoloader (e.g. those elements in $psr4):

```
$path = "Language/{$locale}/{$file}.php"; // system\Language\Language.php line 314
...
$namespace['path'] . $path // system\Autoloader\FileLocator.php line 248
```

Answer (score 1):

Well not sure if anyone is still interested, but I solved this problem debugging some of CodeIgniter 4 classes. Mainly **BaseService::locator** and **FileLocator::search**.

I notice that CodeIgniter was looking for the language path adding the namespace before it, and looping through all the directories and namespaces that were autoloaded.

Here's one example for clarity of the output

```
/var/www/html/app/Config/Helpers/url_helper.php
/var/www/html/modules/admin/Helpers/url_helper.php
/var/www/html/modules/install/Helpers/url_helper.php
/var/www/html/modules/lobby/Helpers/url_helper.php
/var/www/html/system/Helpers/url_helper.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Registrar.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Config/Registrar.php
/var/www/html/modules/admin/Config/Registrar.php
/var/www/html/modules/install/Config/Registrar.php
/var/www/html/modules/lobby/Config/Registrar.php
/var/www/html/system/Config/Registrar.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Events.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Config/Events.php
/var/www/html/modules/admin/Config/Events.php
/var/www/html/modules/install/Config/Events.php
/var/www/html/modules/lobby/Config/Events.php
/var/www/html/system/Config/Events.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Routes.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Config/Routes.php
/var/www/html/modules/admin/Config/Routes.php
/var/www/html/modules/install/Config/Routes.php
/var/www/html/modules/lobby/Config/Routes.php
/var/www/html/system/Config/Routes.php
```

Once I understood the right procedure, I was able to properly modify my app/Config/Autoload.php file.

Here's how it looks like

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config' => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules\Admin' => ROOTPATH . 'modules/admin',
    'Modules\Game' => ROOTPATH . 'modules/install',
    'Modules\Lobby' => ROOTPATH . 'modules/lobby',
];
```

After I did that, the following URLs where added to the list above

```
/var/www/html/app/Language/en/home/home_lang.php
/var/www/html/app/Config/Language/en/home/home_lang.php
/var/www/html/modules/admin/Language/en/home/home_lang.php
/var/www/html/modules/install/Language/en/home/home_lang.php
/var/www/html/modules/lobby/Language/en/home/home_lang.php
/var/www/html/system/Language/en/home/home_lang.php
```

I didn't explore further, so I have no idea why CodeIgniter is not considering something like this:

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config' => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Modules' => ROOTPATH . 'modules',
];
```

I was expecting that the framework would explore all the directories inside it, but I guess it is limited to just one level down.

Finally, this is my directory structure:

- app
- public
- system
- writable
- modules

  - admin

    - Controllers
    - Language

      - en
  - install

    - Controllers
    - Language

      - en
  - lobby

    - Controllers
    - Language

      - en

So my advice are two things:

- Put your modules outside the app folder like CI documentation suggests.
- Explicitly tell CI where your modules are.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. That was beneficial